# Bottom Overflowed by 17 pixels [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

Hi i am following an online tutorial building an app but am getting overflow pixels at the bottom of my card.  I am unable to find the difference between my code from the video and the source code is not provided by the author. From my understanding i am having a 
Column(children:[ClipRRect,Row]) <- in general but i cannot see the Row it is behind the ClipRRect, shouldn't it be below?

````
  final String imagePath, cityName, monthYear, discount;

  final int oldPrice, newPrice;

  CityCard(this.imagePath, this.cityName, this.monthYear, this.discount,
      this.oldPrice, this.newPrice);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 210,
                  width: 160,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    imagePath,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 0.0,
                  bottom: 0.0,
                  height: 60,
                  width: 160,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          colors: [
                            Colors.black,
                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 10,
                  bottom: 10,
                  right: 10,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            cityName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            monthYear,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 2.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                        child: Text(
                          "$discount%",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              Text(
                '${formatCurrency.format(newPrice)}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              Text(
                "(${formatCurrency.format(oldPrice)})",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 13),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```

I am suppose to have a row that shows the new price and the old price below each card. I am able to reveal them if i reduce the height of the Card container but i have no idea why it is overlapping since i am having a Column(children:(ClipRRect,Row)) <- can't see the Row
````

Comment: Did you try `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in your first `Column`?

Comment: Note that, since you have used fixed values you will get little different looks in different different devices. Thats may be the case your dupe with your tutor

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Hi this did not work for me! Fixed it by adjusting the Container Height where i generated my listview of cityCards

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your `Column` inside a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Probably this didn't happen to your instructor because of the size of his device.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this was not giving me what i wanted since I had to scroll up within the RRect to view the prices. Found the solution which was in the container height of 210 which contains the listview, i just increased it to 230 and it worked since it was 17 pixels overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For the bottom overflow pixels, place the Column in SingleChildScrollView for instance:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
    **your code**)));}
```